# What is this style of illustration called?

Tags: illustration

I saw this Oracle illustration yesterday and it was produced by Google Ad randomly on a web page. I love the illustration in the background. I love 'corporate' illustrations especially when they are in a form of a 3D. Microsoft did a similar illustration for their "Visio" product. Now, my questions are:

[image]

1. What do you call these type of illustrations?
2. Is anyone familiar with this illustration?
3. Is there a gallery where I can find these type of 'corporate' illustrations?

Comment: Looks like an isometric vector image to me :]

Comment: this type of perspective is called isometric.

Comment: @Johannes, @jackJoe: You need to make your comments into answers otherwise you won't get any credit.

Comment: Yeah, but DA01 mentions vectors and isometric in his answer as well. I don't think I need to repeat it :]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not meet our [style-identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2929/23061)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure there's a specific style name for that, but some terms that could be applicable:

- flat
- iconography
- isometric
- vector
- infographic

Many of the stock art sites will have collections of all sorts of illustration styles for use. Veer.com is a popular vendor.

Comment: I'm looking for similar illustrations in the corporate design. Especially for Oracle and Microsoft. I'm collecting these.. Anyone famaliar?

Comment: As stated in my answer, check out veer.com

Comment: +1 for isometric and vector as apt descriptions. The rest of those listed don't have to be either isometric or vector